# Is there a way to query the AWS RDS Oracle DB Identifier from SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-web-services, plsql, amazon-rds

When you create a DB in RDS you give it a name (specifically "DB Identifier"). Is there a way to query in SQL from a given instance and get that DB Identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `SYS_CONTEXT()` function -- it can return all sorts of interesting things, including the DB Name:

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME') from dual;
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086) for all the other values that can be used for the second parameter.  This is a funciton that can be called both from a SQL query as above, or from PL/SQL.

Comment: DB_NAME returns the SID, which is NOT what I want. Unfortunately I have tried all of the SYSCONTEXTs and AWS doesn't set them to anything useful to me. All of the IP related calls return the non-routable addresses on the 192 or 10 network. I want to get to the DNS CNAME or the AWS DB Identifier.

Comment: Ugh!  I'm shocked!  I can see AWS clamping down on some parameters for `SYS_CONTEXT()`.  I guess they are being overly careful to avoid SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have OEM Agent installed, you can do:

```
select 
regexp_replace(si.option_setting_value, '\..*', '') db_instance_identifier
from 
rdsadmin.rds_option_settings_info si
where si.option_name = 'OEM_AGENT'
and si.option_setting = 'RDS_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT'
```